# Can a Plasma Cutter use for melt metals?

Tags: metals, molding

Can a Plasma Cutter use for melt metals like Iron, Brass, Stainless Steel ect, ?. Particularly for molding purposes.

If can't, is there any other electric item that doesn't use gases (Acetylene, Butane, Oxygen) for melt metals ?

Edit:

I want to heat a mass of metal up to the melting point and pour that melted metal to a Plaster Parris impression cast. I want to find a electric solution to melt the metal instead of gas.

Comment: Howabout arc furnaces?

Comment: A plasma cutter works simply like that: melt the metal then blow the melted metal.

It should also work with partially melted metal. But if you work with already well melted metals you should use only an air cutter.

The risk is more about how you deal with the high temperatures of the metal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Plasma cutters use a jet of air along with the arc to cut they pretty thoroughly oxidise the metal, plus the jet would just spray molten metal everywhere if you tried to contain it.

In terms of electrical only heating an induction furnace is efficient and scalable, for low melting point metals like pewter and possible some brasses a straightforward restive heating kiln should work but will be less efficient.

Also plaster isn't suitable for casting ferrous metals, the temperatures involved are way too high. Sand or ceramic shell moulds are required for iron and steel.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice. I make the cast by mixing Plaster with building construction cement in 1:2 ratio. It tolerates heat and easy to break.